# Unable to export project from aptana

Tags: air

i am new to adobe air.

I have installed aptana and created a test application.

When i export that application using export feature of aptana and choose application type as "Adobe air package". It generates a file having extension  .airi.

On double clicking that file nothing runs.

Please help me guys.

let me know where i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a .air file is pretty much like a zip file. You can open it with 7-zip, for example, and see the source of your app. The .air extension is probably only a reference for the adobe air runtime. Therefore, my suggestion, as dull as it may seem, is that you manually change the extension to .air.

Comment: This may somehow be related to your problem...: http://cfsilence.com/blog/client/index.cfm/2009/2/19/Problems-Installing-Adobe-AIR-Apps-On-Vista--Try-This